# Create ghost page

Tags: pages

I want to create the ghost page `/foo/` so that it appears in the list of pages, but is unclickable and has no content.

An example use of this is that in my menu it displays the pagename `foo` and when you hover it, it displays the subpages (which are "real" pages) `bar` and `baz`. The URLs of them would be `/foo/bar/` and `/foo/baz/`.

I figured I could simply remove the `<a>` tags of `foo` in Javascript and put a redirect in the `/foo/` page. but that doesn't feel right. What would be an elegant/serverside solution for this problem?

Comment: Please show us your code. Are trying to that in a menu? If so, in which menu? Is this admin or theme facing, etc? This question needs a huge edit and lots of additional information.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way. check for a unique class for the page in the menu or add an unique class. you can do it by checking **CSS classes** under `screen options` in the menu edit page.

lets say the class you added is `ghost-page`

Then in the js file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.ghost-page').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
});
```

But the page will still be accessible by home_url()/page-slug but the above will disable the click event from the menu for this page.

But if you don't want a page to exist then, add a **custom link** to the menu with **#** in the url and add the css class and **label** as `foo`, by doing so there wont be a page to link with and the above js code will disable the click event.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hmm, if this is the only solution I'm a bit disappointed in the flexibility of Wordpress.

Comment: I guess I have found a better solution. I have improved the answer. pls check the bottom of the previous answer.

Comment: You can't put a `#` in the URL.

Comment: You can while creating a custom link for a menu.

Comment: Added an image in the answer... Hope it helps

Comment: Note: the selector should be `jQuery('.ghost-page a')` instead of `jQuery('.ghost-page')`. The class gets added to the parent of `a` which is a `li`

Comment: Also, a big issue is that with you JS, all the subpages under the ghost page aren't clickable as well.

Comment: remove the js code completely and just add the parent menu url with **#** and this should work